# How to specify the attributes of folders in rpm.spec recursively

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpm-spec

The file attribute can be specified in the field of `rpm.spec`, e.g.

```sh
%dir %attr(0770, userA, groupA) /etc/config/
```

My point is, There are many folders under `/etc/config` and I want to specify their attributes the same as `/etc/config`. I don't want to specify them one by one. Is there a way to specify all the folders' attribute under `/etc/config` recursively? Just like `sudo chmod -R 770 /etc/config`?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
%install
...
#whatever in plain bash
chmod -R 770 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/config
chmod 644 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/config/foo/bar/somefile

%files
# the attributes are copied from buildroot, but not user
%{_sysconfdir}/config
%{_sysconfdir}/config/foo/bar/somefile
```

or

```
%install
...
#whatever in plain bash
chmod -R 770 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/config
chmod 644 %{buildroot}%{_sysconfdir}/config/foo/bar/somefile

%files
%defattr(-, userA, groupA, -)
%{_sysconfdir}/config
```

or

```
%files
# fileattr, user, group, dirattr
%defattr(770, userA, groupA, 550)
%{_sysconfdir}/config
```

Answer (score 1):

when you use the `%dir` directive, you tell `rpmbuild` to package only that directory and not the contents recursively (see [here](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-files-list-directives.html)). So why don't you just use:

```
%attr(0770, userA, groupA) /etc/config/
```

to package `/etc/config/` and all subdirectories and files recursively with those attributes?